# Delphi XE2 - TIBOQuery calculated field must be at the last order?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am using TIBOQuery, with "file_full_path" is a calculated field.
First, I open query to get data from database

```
with qryFiles do
begin
  Close;
  ParamByName('id_dre').Value := Self.qryListID_DRE.AsString;
  ParamByName('id_use').Value := rUser.ID_USE;
  Open;
end;
```

Then I load qrery data into TdxMemData named memFiles:

```
memFiles.Close;
memFiles.LoadFromDataSet(qryFiles);
memFiles.Open;
```

And I show value of the "file_full_path" field:

```
ShowMessage(memFiles.FieldByName('file_full_path').Value);
```

Code in OnCalcFields of the query:

```
procedure TfrmDocsGoodRegisterDetail.qryFilesCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet); 
begin 
  DataSet.FieldByName('file_full_path').Value := WideLowerCase(ExtractFileDir(rSys.PathSDK)
                                                + '\' + DataSet.FieldByName('id_dre').AsString
                                                + '\' + DataSet.FieldByName('id_dfo').AsString
                                                + '\' + DataSet.FieldByName('file_name').AsString); 
end;
```

Problem is when I put "file_full_path" at the last in qrery fields order, it works fine. 
[image]

But when I change that field to any other positions (not at the bottom), it return null at ShowMessage line of code.

[image]

Does anyone know why? Please help, thank you.

Comment: Ask author of IBObjects. I would consider this as a bug since calculated fields should be held separately from other permanent fields (it seems that their order matters from what you describe, so it somehow indicates they're mixed together). The problem may very well be that the calculation event is not fired in case when the calculated field is not at the end of such _"all fields"_ collection. But that is just a guess (cannot verify this). What I can say is that order should not matter.

Comment: Fwiw, I agree with @Victoria that this seems to be a bug, since the position of a calculated field in the `Fields` collection should not make any difference to the calculated values.